# How can I start freshly? Libraries mess Wemos D1 Mini

Tags: arduino-uno, library

I am using a wemosd1 MINI which has a ESP8266 module. I am using it for an IoT project, however a lot has been going wrong.  With libraries and version types. I want to start over but noticed that simply reinstalling arduino didnt do tha trick. How can i restart?

Comment: Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: Delete your IDE's data folder and libraries folder.

Comment: I don't understand, what your problem is. If you have a big mess of libraries, you can just delete the libraries from the libraries folder

Comment: Windows! Deleting the libraries causes conflicts in my program i feel like i deleted some curical ones as well.

Comment: Of course if you delete the libraries you won't be able to compile your program. It's after deleting that you need to the install the right versions of the right libraries.